# get the max count value in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE nomenclator SYSTEM "nomenclator.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="nomenclator.xsl"?>
<nomenclator>
 <adresa cod="300368" tip="Strada">
  <nume>St. Karadjic Vuc</nume>
  <alias cand="2008">Karadjici Vuk St</alias>
 </adresa>
 <adresa cod="300050" tip="Bulevard">
  <nume>Miron Costin</nume>
  <alias cand="1990"> 12 Encsel Mauriciu</alias>
 </adresa>
 <adresa cod="300040" tip="Bulevard">
  <nume>Miron Costin</nume>
  <alias cand="1990"> 12 Encsel Mauriciu</alias>
 </adresa> 
 <adresa cod="300040" tip="Bulevard">
  <nume>Miron Costin</nume>
  <alias cand="9"> 12 Encsel Mauriciu</alias> 
 </adresa>
</nomenclator>
```

What I want to do is to get the maximum count from cod. In this example code 300040 appears for 3 times, so this code has the maximum occurence.

Here is what I tried to do:

```html
<xsl:for-each select="nomenclator/adresa">
  <xsl:call-template name="sortare">
   <xsl:with-param name="param1" select="@cod"/> 
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:for-each>

<xsl:template name="sortare">
 <xsl:param name="param1" select="0"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="count(document('nomenclator.xml')//adresa[@cod=$param1])"/>>
</xsl:template>
```

Please help me with a solution. The idea is that I have to sort by count, but the problem is that the sort can be done only after for-each.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. If you only want to sort the `adresa` nodes by their frequency, you don't need to know the *maximum* count. It would be best if you showed us the expected output. -- P.S. Please indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: The expected result should be 300040 , becouse this code appears two times and the others only once. (XSLT 1.0)

Comment: Is that supposed to be the **ENTIRE** result of the XSL transformation?? Just this one piece of data? -- **P.S. Please indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.**

Comment: Yes, just this one piece of data. I mentioned XSLT1.0

Comment: Sorry, didn't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The expected result should be 300040 , becouse this code appears two
>   times and the others only once.

If that's the only result you're looking for, it can be obtained quite simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="adresa-by-cod" match="adresa" use="@cod" />

<xsl:template match="/nomenclator">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="adresa">
            <xsl:sort select="count(key('adresa-by-cod', @cod))" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <xsl:value-of select="@cod"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example input, the **result** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>300040</output>
```

Note the use of a *key*, instead of:

```
<xsl:sort select="count(//adresa[@cod=current()/@cod])" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
```

although that would have worked, too.